# How to make label stretch on tabitem in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem when I try to use a click event on a Label that is the Content of a TabItem Header.

```
   <TabItem Name="prod" MouseLeftButtonDown="prod_MouseLeftButtonDown">
          <TabItem.Header >
                <Label Content="Prod" MouseLeftButtonDown="prod_MouseLeftButtonDown" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
          </TabItem.Header>
```

The problem is that the Label does not occupy the entire TabItem Header so if the user clicks in the margin of the Header the Click event is not triggered.

[image]

You can see that I would like it to be no spaces where the red line is now.

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is apply some negative `Margin` and complement it  with `Padding`. There is always ***hard coded*** margin for the ContentPresenter. So this way should work consistently once you adjusted the `Margin` well (such as by trial and error). The `Padding` is positive and has the inverse values of `Margin`. Here is what I've tried, it works on my side, you can tweak the margin according to your requirement:

```
<Label Content="Prod" MouseLeftButtonDown="prod_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Margin="-8,-3,-8,-3" Padding="8,3,8,3"/>
```

Without tweaking like this, you cannot easily change the hard coded `Margin` ***unless*** you copy and modify the standard template of the `TabControl`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply trigger the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event on the `TabItem` itself.. and not on the label...

```
   <TabItem Name="prod" MouseLeftButtonDown="prod_MouseLeftButtonDown">
      <TabItem.Header >
            <Label Content="Prod"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
      </TabItem.Header>
 </TabItem>
```

Comment: It's not such easy. If you try this it has no effect (clicking on the margin area has no effect). Also `TabItem` does not just contain `Header`, it contains ***all large content below***. So if there is some content below, clicking on the content also fire the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event. If you use `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`, clicking on the margin does fire the event ***but*** still clicking any where on the `TabItem` (including the large content below) will fire the event. That's of course not desired. We seem stuck with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `height` and `width` property of the label to `Auto`

```
 <Label Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Content="Prod" MouseLeftButtonDown="prod_MouseLeftButtonDown" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) :The width property

> > Gets or sets the width of the control.(Inherited from Control.)

and the height property

> > Gets or sets the height of the control.(Inherited from Control.)

Comment: @Hopeless did you try it without setting the margins?

Comment: yes, I've tried the exact code. The problem here is there is always a margin around. Changing the `Width` and `Height` cannot change that fact.

Comment: oh. This did the job for me once.  Hopefully your answer will do the trick  :)

Comment: maybe that was when the problem was different (such as there was actually no hard coded margin), anyway this has been tested (you can download some simple XAML editor such as Kaxaml) and try it quickly (don't need to create a demo VS project).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `ContentPresenter` itself and modify it accordingly. You can also get fancy and use it as a style for all of your `TabItems`.

```
    <TabControl Width="500">
        <TabControl.Items>
            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    Prod
                </TabItem.Header>
                <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="-8, -3, -8, 0" >
                            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                <TextBlock MouseLeftButtonDown="prod_MouseLeftButtonDown" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </ContentPresenter.Content>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl.Items>
    </TabControl>
```